# SSIS manage connection string passwords on multiple packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, passwords, connection-string, change-password

Our company has different servers using Oracle, Teradata, SQLServer databases that need to change password every 3 months, and I have quite a few SSIS packages that point to those databases.  Is that anyway I can centralized the password on all the connection strings so I can just change the passwords on only one place?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Environment variables for your connection strings? You can set the packages to reference a connectionstring variable defined on your respective environments, in that way once you've done the mapping exercise you would just need to update the variable on the environment rather than all the packages.